# Getting socket hang up when trying to make a http request to localhost server created through app.listen (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, localhost, axios

For the code below I get a "socket hang up" error when making the axios (get) request to the server that was created through app.listen, does anyone have any insight?

```
 var server = app.listen(4000, () => {
        if (getFeedId(sub) === 2) {
            return axios.get('https://localhost:4000', (data) => {
                try {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    var newData = JSON.parse(data);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the infinite recursion? shouldn't the axios.get call not be fired until after the socket is created since it is inside the callback

Comment: oh, my error. Theres no recursion. However could you show the rest of your code?